# How to set up the correct 'View' for VBA Project in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, settings

Not sure if this is the correct place to post this but this issue is driving me insane....

**The Issue:**

I have come to use my PC after the weekend and for some reason the layout of the VBA Project stuff is completely messed up...

Usually when my VBA is set up very nicely in what I believe is the standard viewing mode IE the Project box to the left and the code to right and the intermediate window at the bottom...

**For some reason now I get the following:**

[image]

As you can see it is just the code...

**I then click on the project explorer window and the project details appear, but as one ridiculously large page....**

[image]

**Then I minimise the window and alter its shape to try and get it at least look like it used to...**

[image]

**I can live with this to an extent although everything is floating and annoying... But now, every time I click onto a module (to view the code). It opens each module as its own seperate window!**

[image]

**This as you can imagine is unsustainable when working with as lot of code and having to flick between different modules**

**What I have Tried:**

I have tried looking in different settings and I can not see anything different...
I have restarted my PC and it is still the same...
I have tired opening a different spreadsheet and still the same....

**Does anyone have any suggestions? I just want it to be back to the simple layout of everything joined together etc...**

Comment: Grab the title of the project window and drag it to the left until the (half visible) window changes it's form. It is now "docked" to the left part of the VBE. Resize it to fit your needs. Now maximize one of the code windows.

Comment: Hi Tom, you are right this belongs maybe on the sister-site to Stack Overflow SuperUser it will likely be closed here. On top of what @FunThomas says check Tools->Options->Docking, ensure everything is ticked except object browser. Then the drag and drop windows should stop floating if you move them over the edges of the main editor window

Comment: @FunThomas That worked brillantly! Thanks....